# Apache permissions issue

Tags: permissions, apache2

I have changed my `DocumentRoot` to `/home/user/www`. To achieve that I have just changed the 2 occurrences of the path at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`. 
The permissions of `/home/user/www` are 0774. I have added the www-data user to my user's group and the owner of `/home/user/www` is my own user and group (`user:user`).

The problem is that Apache can't write to this directory. It can write only if I set www-data as owner, but if I do that, I can't write at the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have added the www-data user to my user's group and the owner of `/home/user/www` is my own user and group (`user:user`).

This way, you have give yourself the rights to edit Apache files.

What you need to do is the opposite: give Apache the rights to edit your files:

```
sudo adduser www-data $USER
```

This way you can have `/home/user/www` owned by `$USER:$USER`: you will be able to edit files, Apache will be able to edit them.

This may not be enough, however. You said:

> The permissions of `/home/user/www` are 0774.

Nice, but: you first have to be sure that the mode bits of `/`, `/home` and `/home/user` are correct. And that's still not enough: even if Apache can access `/home/user/www`, you need to be sure that it can access the directory contents too.

If you want to make experiments and see what's wrong, try:

```
sudo -u www-data ls /home/user/www
sudo -u www-data cat /home/user/www/some-file
sudo -u www-data touch /home/user/www/some-file
```

Comment: And who should be the owner of www after that? www-data:www-data ?

Comment: @user199003: I've updated my answer.

Comment: `sudo adduser www-data $USER` is exactly what I did before, probably I didn't explain it properly. I have tried `sudo -u www-data ls /home/user/www` and `sudo -u www-data cat /home/user/www/some-file` and they both work. What do you mean by `the mode bits of /, /home and /home/user are correct`? Mode bits? What is that?

Comment: I have a Wordpress in www and it can't install a plugin, it asks for FTP - this is the actual problem.

Comment: Even if I set permissions of 0777, it still won't work. It works for apache only if www-data is the owner.

Comment: @barakuda28: **1.** Mode bits are those things that you set via `chmod`. **2.** What does it mean "it asks for FTP"? Apache is a HTTP server, it does not provide FTP access. **3.** What exactly is not working? If `sudo -u www-data ls`, `cat` and `touch` work, then Apache can read and write files in your directory.